# SwifUI, iOS 13 show view on top of Navigationview in destination view

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I am working on app supporting iOS 13 using SwiftUI, I have custom activity indicator(UIViewRepresentable) on which is displayed on Api call

In main screen where I have created NavigationView, on top of that I am able to add the activity indicator view which is able to cover the navigation bar also,

But in detail view which is navigated using navigation link, I tried the same code but the activity indicator view is displayed below navigation bar(which is not covering the navigation bar)

> struct DetailView: View {
>
> ```
> @State private var show = false
>
> var body: some View {
>     ZStack {
>         Button("showSpinner") {
>             self.show.toggle()
>         }
>     }
>     .modifier(CoverNavigationBar(show: $show) {
>         CustomActiviyIndicatorView()
>             .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
>     })
>     
> } }
> ```

> struct CoverNavigationBar<Cover: View>: ViewModifier {

> ```
> @Binding var show: Bool
> let cover: () -> Cover
>
> func body(content: Content) -> some View {
>     ZStack {
>         content
>         if self.show {
>             cover()
>         }
>     }
> } }
> ```

Comment: Wherer is your NavigationView? It should be placed in the ZStack.

Comment: The main view has navigationview, which has no problem